# What part of this is this wrong? $\sum_{n\geq1}\frac1{n(n+1)}=-1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Here is my attempt to find $$P=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac1{n(n+1)}$$
First we note that $$\int_0^1 x^n dx=\frac1{n+1}$$
Plugging in gives
$$P=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac1n\int_0^1x^ndx$$
$$P=\int_0^1\sum_{n\geq1}\frac1nx^ndx$$
$$P=\int_0^1\sum_{n\geq1}\int x^{n-1}dxdx$$
$$P=\int_0^1 \int\sum_{n\geq1}x^{n-1}dxdx$$
$$P=\int_0^1 \int\sum_{n\geq0}x^{n}dxdx$$
$$P=\int_0^1 \int\frac{dx}{1-x}dx$$
$$P=\int_0^1 \log(1-x)dx$$
$$P=-1$$
But Wolfram alpha says $P=1$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: As an alternative to solve or to check the result (without using wolfy) recall that by telescoping $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac1{n(n+1)}=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac1{n}-\sum_{n\geq1}\frac1{n+1}=1\color{red}{-\frac12+\frac12-\frac13+\frac13-\frac14+\ldots}=1$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that

$$\int_0^x \frac1{1-t}\, dt = -\ln(1-t)|_{t=0}^{t=x}=-\ln(1-x)$$

Side remark:

You have reuse $x$ for different purposes. Try to avoid that.

Comment: To make this clearer I would say the error comes earlier, when you relabel $\tfrac{1}{n}x^n$ as the indefinite integral of $x^{n-1}$. It should be $\int_0^x t^{n-1}dt$.